# Show that B|A|+ A|B| and A|B|−B|A| are orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Where A and B are vectors, I personally am not really sure what this question is even really asking, maybe I'm interpreting it wrong. I know how to take dot products and cross products but is that even involved here?

Comment: Yes, expand the dot product of these vectors : you will obtain 4 terms that cancel two by two, getting finally $0$ which is synonym to orthogonality.

Comment: What do you mean by expand the dot product? is B|A|= cos(0)BdotA?

Comment: No, this formula with cos is of no use here ; use the distributivity property $\left(B|A|+A|B|\right)\cdot\left(A|B|-B|A|\right)=(B|A| \ \cdot \ A|B|)+(B|A| \ \cdot \ B|A|)+ ...$

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: I am going to give a graphical proof.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah you should use the dot product here to calculate $$\left(B|A|+A|B|\right)\cdot\left(A|B|-B|A|\right)$$ and you want to show that this is equal to zero. Remember that you can distribute this dot-product and pull out scalars, and that $A\cdot A=|A|^2$.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Geometrical proof of the orthogonality of these vectors :

$\|A\|B$ and $\|B\|A$ have the same norm ($\|A\|.\|B\|$).

Thus, their sum $\|A\|B +\|B\|A$ is the diagonal of a rhombus, which is orthogonal to the other diagonal, which can be expressed as the difference $ \|B\|A - \|A\|B$.

In other words, we deal with the internal and external line bissectors of the axes defined by $A$ and $B$ resp.

[image]

Remark : we would have had a similar result by adding and subtracting the norm-one vectors $\frac{A}{\|A\|} $ and $\frac{B}{\|B\|}.$

Answer (score 0):

Two vectors are orthogal if their inner product is zero

$(A\|B\| + \|A\|B)\cdot (A\|B\| - \|A\|B) = A\cdot A \|B\|^2 + \|A\|\|B\|A\cdot B - \|A\|\|B\| A\cdot B -\|A\|^2B\cdot B$

$\|A\|^2 = A\cdot A$

And as you see everything cancels.

Geometrically $(A\|B\| + \|A\|B)$ and $(A\|B\| - \|A\|B)$ are the diagonals of a rhombus.